Get Docker Container Id in Logback
I want to have container id in my logs. I am using logback as a logging tool. How can I get container id inlogback-spring.xml configuration. My thoughts, As the container id is hostname in a docker container I can set the container id as environment variable then access it via logback-spring.xml. Is it a bad idea or are there any better alternative to this solution.
logback-spring.xml
<configuration>    
    <appender name="CONSOLE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder>
            <!--- Some have I get container id --->
            <pattern>%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} [${CONTAINER_ID}] %-5level %logger{36} %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <root level="info">
        <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE" />
    </root>
</configuration>

Thanks for your response.

Have you tried ${HOSTNAME}. Typically for containers, containerId is mapped to HOSTNAME environment variable.

I take it the application writing the logfile is running inside the container, and you are asking how that should be configured.
In that case it will hardly be possible.
Docker virtualization tries to isolate applications from each other such that they do not notice. While you could try to set an environment variable to tell the application about the container id, be aware that id is generated when the container is created from an image. So you do not know what value to set in the variable until it is too late.
That means the concept of storing the logs with appropriate container id is left to the outside world. Look for logging drivers in Kubernetes, Docker swarm or whatever you use.
Also I seriously doubt the container id is the same as the hostname as I have seen otherwise. However it might be the case in your environment.
So you could have an entrypoint script that evaluates the hostname, sets an environment variable and then starts your application. All you need to do is to include that environment variable into your logs.

I am not using any orchestration tool due to the limitations I have. My problems is when I collect the logs from different containers that is running same application and put it in a same file. I want to identify which container is printing the error logs. Can I somehow achieve this? It doesn't need to be container id.

Have a look at https://docs.docker.com/engine/logging/configure/. The syslog driver seems quite suitable in your case.
